# Mobile Device Overlay doesn't fit screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a simple div overlay with the following CSS:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
display:none;
cursor:default;
z-index:101;
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

jQuery is used to fade it in.
All works great on all browsers, but when viewing it on mobile devices the div isn't 100% tall. I've also tried the following:

Setting the div's dimensions to `screen.width` and `screen.height...` same results

Adding the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />`
tag to the index ... which screwed a ton of stuff up and made the overlay about 25% width of the phone....

I've never run into an issue like this before and can't seem to see any problems with the CSS.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`.

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
opacity:.5;
cursor:default;
z-index:101;
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ditching the height, and set bottom to 0

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
display:none;
cursor:default;
z-index:101;
```

However, screens would be good if possible.

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work and is showing up at about 25% of the entire screen.